# Can the data be displayed without using Adapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I am new to android programming.

I have *managed* to create an app to save data given by user. But now I want to display data in new activity. I am clueless about what should I do. My output on the new activity should look like the following.

[image: Displayed Result]

Since I only have the two rows I guess it is OK avoid using adapter, but I have not clue how to accomplish this. Please help me. As I already said I am new to android programming. So something that you might think is obvious will not feel as obvious to me as it does to you yet.

Comment: have you actually attempted anything ? read the docs and the developers guide ?

Comment: @Rohan I did try to read them but couldn't understand them clearly and I accept that I need to learn more but I am frustrated with every solution that I see on internet about displaying data from database, and everyone seems to be using Adapter. Hence I wished to know if there is any other way which may be inefficient for sure but easy enough to grasp. Also, I think you should be kind to people who know less than you. If you think this was that trivial then please answer it or provide decent links at least. Saying "there exist solution to the problem of singularity of black hole" won't do.

Comment: You can create a table with 2 rows that have 5 columns of Textviews in each. If you id your Texviews right, ie (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) and (b1,b2,b3,b4, b5) you could easy create some logic to Set the Text in each column automatically using some loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your question has two parts:

1- How you send data to the new activity?

2- How to display data in the new activity?

for the first question you can do in couple of ways but two of them I mention here:

- You can put the data in a `Bundle` and attach the bundle to the `Intent`
- You can use `ContentProvider` and access your data from another application using a `URI`

for the second part you can use different layouts but the most popular are:

- `GridView`
- `RecyclerView`

If your program scales (not stuck in two students), you need to use adapters. You find lots of examples and tutorials on the internet for them

Answer (score 0):

Not in a listview.  A listview needs the adapter to display anything.  But you don't need a listview for this-  you need a TableView.  Those have a fixed number of rows (generally), but are made for showing rows and columns of data.

Of course if your full solution has N students, you need a listview and you need an adapter.